# Cannot read property 'title' of null - error message in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

Under the pages folder, I have a subfolder called 'postings' which stores another subfolder called '_quidproquo'.  This last subfolder holds a file called 'index.vue'.  I have received an error messages which states that it cannot read property 'title' of null for my nuxt.js code.  Can someone please advise where I am going wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="single-post-page">
   <section class="post">
    <h1 class="post-title">
      {{ loadedPost.title }}
    </h1>
  <div class="post-details">
    <div class="post-detail">
      Last updated on {{ loadedPost.updatedDate | date }}
    </div>
    <div class="post-detail">
      Written by {{ loadedPost.author }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="post-content">
    {{ loadedPost.content }}
  </p>
</section>
<section class="post-feedback">
  <p>Let me know what you think about the project, send an email to: <a href="mailto: blahblah@blah.com">meh@meh.com</a>.</p>
</section>
</div>
</template>

<script>
// import PostList from '@/components/Posts/PostList'
// import axios from 'axios'

export default {

  middleware: 'log',

  components: {
// PostList
  },

  asyncData (context) {
    return context.app.$axios.$get('/posts/' + context.params.id + '.json')
     .then((data) => {
     return {
      loadedPost: data
    }
  })
  .catch(error => context.error(error))
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>
.single-post-page {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:93vh;
}

.post {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .post {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    }
}

.post-title {
 margin: 0;
}

.post-details {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .post-details {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

.post-detail {
    color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.post-feedback a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post-feedback a:hover,
.post-feedback a:active {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please read the docs how to structure Vue components. At least you need to define `data()` function and provide all reactive values you want to use in your template (e.g. `loadedPost`. Also since you fetch data from a remote endpoint you should add some preloader and different states (loading/success/error) in your template.

Comment: could you please just `console.log(data)` to see how your data looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling 'title' property of 'loadedPost' object but there is a few issues:

1. there is nothing named 'loadedPost' in either computed or data object in vue instance
2. you are calling for 'loadedPost' in an API call which may take time for the result to resolve

So here is what you can do:

1. define loadedPost as an empty object in vue data object
2. update the loadedPost when the API call is resolved

here is the demo:

vue template:

```
<template>
    // ...
    <h1>{{ loadedPost.title }}</h1>
    // ...
</template>
```

script section:

```
//...
export default {
data() {
  return {
    loadedPost: {},
  };
},
methods: {
  apiCall() {
    apiCallFunction().then((result) => { this.loadedPost = result });
  },
},
}
```

this way when the loadedPost gets updated, template updates too.

Comment: Thanks @hamid-niakan , that was exactly what I was after.  I needed to modify your script slightly but it works

Comment: @jackie glad it helped